# Dealing with TLS on gRPC

Tags: android, ssl, tls1.2, grpc, grpc-java

I am connecting to a server which has TLS support with SSL certs. I am getting a SSL Handshake error on Android app client. I also use `useTransportSecurity()` to deal with TLS negotiation type. Is there any workaround to get away with this error without certificate pinning?

**Error encountered:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: protocol negotiation failed

    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpProtocolNegotiator.negotiate(OkHttpProtocolNegotiator.java:96)

    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpProtocolNegotiator$AndroidNegotiator.negotiate(OkHttpProtocolNegotiator.java:147)

    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpTlsUpgrader.upgrade(OkHttpTlsUpgrader.java:63)

    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$2.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:474)

    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

---

**And this is how I generate my channel :**

```
ManagedChannel mChannel = OkHttpChannelBuilder.forAddress(host, port)
        .useTransportSecurity()
        .build();
```

Appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

ALPN is failing during the TLS handshake, which prevents gRPC from negotiating HTTP/2. Either you aren't connecting to a gRPC / HTTP/2 server or your client's TLS library is too old.

Please review the [SECURITY.md](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#tls-on-android) documentation. Namely, you probably want to "install" the Play Services Dynamic Security Provider into the runtime when your app starts.

Comment: The endpoint needed an ALPN TLS support and that worked like a charm. However, I would still wonder why Android needs to install Dynamic Security Provider. I tried in some of the new and old Android devices I have and I don't seem to stumble upon any issue

Comment: From SECURITY.md: "Although ALPN mostly works on newer Android releases (especially since 5.0), there are bugs and discovered security vulnerabilities that are only fixed by upgrading the security provider."

Some of the bugs are races with library calls done in other parts of the application (like if you use NPN elsewhere in your application). Those sorts of things will trigger "randomly."

Also, older devices may be using NPN instead of ALPN. That may work today, but requires NPN on the server. But NPN support is disappearing in the ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

it might be rather a matter how you create the server; see [SECURITY.md](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/7d455964f601ce9d3bdd57e79f0c7b0c065b2ce3/SECURITY.md) for `Mutual TLS` ...

```
Server server = NettyServerBuilder.forPort(8443)
    .sslContext(GrpcSslContexts.forServer(certChainFile, privateKeyFile)
    .trustManager(clientCAsFile)
    .clientAuth(ClientAuth.REQUIRE)
    .build());
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

This error comes from the ALPN TLS extension, which I needed my SSL endpoint to support.  I was using NPN, and that is why I was unable to connect.

Posted by Carl Mastrangelo in grpc.io google groups